# How do I keep track of cells that have been selected using NSIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have multiple sections in my `UITableView` that each have a different number of `UITableViewCells`.

I would like to keep track of cells that have been selected for each section and display an image for the cells that have been selected.

So I was thinking about storing them in an array:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     someArray.append(indexPath)
}
```

and then displaying the image for cells that have been selected:

```
 for indices in self.someArray {
     if indices == indexPath {
         cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
     } else {
         cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "unselected"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
     }
 }
```

I'd also like to make it so that only one cell per section can be selected at a time and that each selection made persists for each section.

The selections just don't stay put as they should. Every time I make a selection in section 0 for some row, it then also selects the same row index for my other sections.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest maintaining a data model for your view controller which keeps all the selected states for each cell in your various sections. (Choose a more apt name that describes your cell items).

```
struct Element {
    var isSelected: Bool // selection state
}
```

Then your view controller would have a data model as so:

```
 var dataModel: [[Element]] // First array level is per section, and second array level is all the elements in a section (e.g. dataModel[0][4] is the fifth element in the first section)
```

This array would likely be initialized to a bunch of Elements where isSelected is false, presuming you start with all rows deselected.

Now your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function would look something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Check if there are any other cells selected... if so, mark them as deselected in favour of this newly-selected cell
    dataModel[indexPath.section] = dataModel[indexPath.section].map({$0.isSelected = false}) // Go through each element and make sure that isSelected is false

    // Now set the currently selected row for this section to be selected
    dataModel[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].isSelected = true
  }
```

(A more efficient way might be to keep the last selected row for each section and mark that false instead of mapping the entire subarray.)

Now, in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, you must display whether or not a cell is selected based on your dataModel. If you are not maintaining your selected state in a data model, as soon as a cell scrolls off screen it will lose its selected state. Furthermore, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will reuse a cell that might reflect your selected state if you do not properly refresh your cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourCellIdentifier") as! YourCellType

    // If your data model says this cell should be selected, show the selected image
    if dataModel[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].isSelected {
      cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
      cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "unselected"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
  }
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Makes sense. So it xcode doesn't like this line: dataModel[indexPath.section] = dataModel[indexPath.section].map({$0.isSelected = false})

Comment: Also, i'm getting: fatal error: Index out of range for if dataModel[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].isSelected {

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try running the code myself! You could replace the map with a for loop going through each element in the sub array and making sure it is deselected. As for the index out of range, perhaps you need to implement tableView: numberOfSectionsInTableView to return the correct number of sections, similarly to tableView: numberOfRowsInSection. Both should return values based on the .count property of your dataModel and that way you shouldn't get an index out of range...

Comment: Okay, I got it all figured out on my end. This worked out perfectly :)